# Why was the broken house in forest fixed and what does it imply?

Tags: ending, the-kings-of-summer

In the end of *The Kings of Summer*, the broken house in the forest that Joe,  Patrick and Biaggio built was being fixed. What is it implying? Do they still go there to have fun?